# RecyclerView not being populated (getItemCount() is returning zero)

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I looked at the other questions on SO about this, and matched by code word for word but I must have missed something because nothing is working. getItemCount() is returning zero, but I debugged my data list and it seemed to add all my data properly, so something is going wrong with the communication to the adapter.

Please tell me what's going wrong here!

Below is my code for MainActivity.java:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.parse.FindCallback;
import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.ParseQuery;
import com.parse.ParseUser;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class Profile_Page extends ActionBarActivity {
    UserLocalStore userLocalStore;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private DataAdapter adapter;
    private Context context;
    final LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    public List<Information> data = new ArrayList<>();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile__page);
        ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
        String struser = currentUser.getUsername();
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView); 

        Button logoutBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.logOutBtn);



        adapter = new DataAdapter(getApplicationContext(), getData()); 
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter); 
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));

   public List<Information> getData()
{
    ParseQuery <ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("ParseClassName");
        query.whereEqualTo("author", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) { 
                if (e == null) {
                    for (ParseObject getData : list) { 
                        Information current = new Information();
                        current.thing= getData.getString("Thing");                                           
                        data.add(current); 
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        //for some reason, data isn't getting transferred to adapter


                    }

                } else {
                    //something went wrong
                }

            }


        });
return data;
    }


    public void logOut(View view)
    {
        // Logout current user
        ParseUser.logOut();
        finish();
    }
}
```

Code for DataAdapter:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Chronometer;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;


public class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DataAdapter.MyViewHolder>
{
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    List<Information> data = Collections.emptyList();



    public DataAdapter(Context context, List<Information> data) 
    {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.data= data;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_layout, parent, false); 
        MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view); 
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        Information current = data.get(position);
        holder.tv.setText(current.thing);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount()
    {   Log.d("datasize", String.valueOf(data.size()));
        return data.size();
    }
    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {    TextView tv;




        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tv= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.thingID);


        }
    }
}
```

Information.java

```
public class Information
{
    public String thing;


}
```

Recycler_view_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Dummy Text"
        android:id="@+id/thingID"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Activity in which the RecyclerView is added:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.android.blah.Profile_Page"
    >


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/recyclerView" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Log out"
        android:id="@+id/logOutBtn"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:onClick="logOut"
        android:layout_marginTop="85dp" />


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/logOutBtn" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I am no expert in the Parse API, but I would assume that a `findInBackground()` method is asynchronous. In that case, `data` is empty when you create your `DataAdapter`. Also, do not use `getApplicationContext()` for creating a `LayoutInflater`. Call `getLayoutInflater()` on the `Activity`. Otherwise, your styles and themes will not be honored.

Comment: To deal with the fact that data could be empty due to an async call, I made getData() a separate function and called it as such: 

adapter = new DataAdapter(getApplicationContext(), getData()); 

Still nothing worked though.

Could you explain a bit about what you meant by using getApplicationContext() for creating a LayoutInflater? Not sure what you're referring to

Comment: "I made getData() a separate function" -- that does not change asynchronous behavior. "Could you explain a bit about what you meant by using getApplicationContext()" -- get rid of every occurrence of `getApplicationContext()` in your code shown above.

Comment: found a solution yet?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe if u set adapter inside done method it will work. Insert bottom for loop.

```
adapter = new DataAdapter(getApplicationContext(), data); 
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter); 
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
```

Comment: @CommonsWare pitched the same idea--that data would be empty. I put getting the data in a separate function and called it like so:

adapter = new DataAdapter(getApplicationContext(), getData());

Still didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a call to RecyclerView.Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() whenever the relevant dataset has changed.

Comment: Added this in my for loop but didn't do anything

Comment: Can you add this to an onClick function? Additionally, adapter = new DataAdapter(getApplicationContext(), getData());  doesn't seem right. Your adapter should point to a data structure like an ArrayList.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should do like this:

```
mXxxData.clear();  
mXxxData.addAll(reqForInternetData);  
mRecyclerViewAdapter.notifyItemInserted(0);
```

That is worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the adapter only after setting the layout manager

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new  
LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
adapter = new DataAdapter(getApplicationContext(), data); 
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```